# fstream.h and iostream.h with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Code that worked great in older versions of Visual Studio no longer compile. For example:

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iostream.h>
```

no longer compile.  I'm trying to read in a binary data file using VC++ and VS2010.  Why do such basic tools no longer work?

Don

Comment: Your code didn't come through. You need to mark it up so we can see it.

Comment: Posting the error messages would also help. Just "doesn't compile" isn't very informative.

Comment: "Older versions" is a misnomer, the proper word is "antique".  Personally I like "from the previous century".

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (at least according to modern standards), you don't have to write the extensions of the standard header files:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

Some compilers will just generate warnings when you write the extension, but I guess new versions of Visual treat it as an error.

Comment: If your code is old enough that you still use the .h variants, you may also need to sprinkle `using namespace std;` judiciously throughout your files. Not the best solution but depending on the code it may be the most practical.